# How to make an infinite list of a..z concatenated with 1, then 2, etc

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to create an infinite list in Haskell which takes the letters a..z and then repeats them suffixed with 1 ("a1 ... z1"), then 2 ("a2".."z2"), etc.

At the moment the furthest I've got is using a list comprehension to generate a list of every string combination possible from the two lists of a-z and 1-9,
however I can't figure out how to then apply this to my problem. I have also tried to use the map function but couldn't figure how to apply it to my problem either

```hs
variables :: [Var]
variables = [x : y | y <- "" : variables, x <- ['a'..'z'] ++ ['0'..'9']]
```

Typing `[variables !! i | i <- [0,1,25,26,27,100,3039]]` into ghci should give:
`["a","b","z","a1","b1","w3","x116"]`, but at the moment the result I'm getting is: `["a","b","z","0","1","2b","plb"]`. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Hint: you need to pull from 2 separate lists (not a concatenation of 2), and the "numbers" list should be the infinite list `[1..]`

Answer (score 5):

Use a comprehension a an infinite sequence:

```
Prelude> let variables = [l:show x | x <- [1..],  l <- ['a'..'z']]
Prelude> take 100 variables
["a1","b1","c1","d1","e1","f1","g1","h1","i1","j1","k1","l1","m1","n1","o1","p1","q1","r1","s1","t1","u1","v1","w1","x1","y1","z1","a2","b2","c2","d2","e2","f2","g2","h2","i2","j2","k2","l2","m2","n2","o2","p2","q2","r2","s2","t2","u2","v2","w2","x2","y2","z2","a3","b3","c3","d3","e3","f3","g3","h3","i3","j3","k3","l3","m3","n3","o3","p3","q3","r3","s3","t3","u3","v3","w3","x3","y3","z3","a4","b4","c4","d4","e4","f4","g4","h4","i4","j4","k4","l4","m4","n4","o4","p4","q4","r4","s4","t4","u4","v4"]
```

Just use `(++)` over that list and `['a'..'z']` to prepend the single char lists, notice that since `'a' :: char` you need to transform it to `String` beforehand

```
Prelude> let variables = [l:[] | l <- ['a'..'z']] ++ [l:show x | x <- [1..],  l <- ['a'..'z']]
Prelude> take 100 variables
["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","a1","b1","c1","d1","e1","f1","g1","h1","i1","j1","k1","l1","m1","n1","o1","p1","q1","r1","s1","t1","u1","v1","w1","x1","y1","z1","a2","b2","c2","d2","e2","f2","g2","h2","i2","j2","k2","l2","m2","n2","o2","p2","q2","r2","s2","t2","u2","v2","w2","x2","y2","z2","a3","b3","c3","d3","e3","f3","g3","h3","i3","j3","k3","l3","m3","n3","o3","p3","q3","r3","s3","t3","u3","v3"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but how would it get it to have "a", "b" ... "z" at the start of the list?

Comment: @JackBarber, use `++`?

Comment: Pull `x` from `[0..]`, and replace `show x` with `(if x == 0 then [] else show x)`.